# ListBox context Menu Not firing wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

i have a devexpress ListBoxEdit control with a context menu.
hear is my design`

```
<dxe:ListBoxEdit x:Name="lstEventsList"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Tag="{Binding DataContext}" >
                        <mvvm:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <mvvm:EventToCommand EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" Command="{Binding GetReferenceCodeListOnEventSelect}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                        </mvvm:Interaction.Triggers>

                        <dxe:ListBoxEdit.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding SyncToMediaDevice}" Header="SYNC"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>

                            </ContextMenu>

                        </dxe:ListBoxEdit.ContextMenu>
                    </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
```

now problem is menu context command are not working..binding property is

```
public ICommand SyncToMediaDevice
    {
        get
        {
            return _syncToMediaDevice;
        }
        set
        {
            _syncToMediaDevice = value;
        }
    }`
```

Please help me thanks`

Comment: As I can see you set DataContext in ContextMenu... this datacontaxt override context in menuitem... so obviously that command binding not work.

Comment: What is your PlacementTarget.Tag?  Is it ViewModel with SyncToMediaDevice command?